# why can't my robot properly execute a bash script?

Tags: robotframework

**Robot Code:**

```
*** Tasks ***
Build and Deploy
    Import Library    Process
    Run Process /Users/jcastro2/code/flutter/arkiteki/build_deploy.sh   shell=yes
```

**/Users/jcastro2/code/flutter/arkiteki/build_deploy.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
flutter build web --web-renderer html
scp -r ~/code/flutter/arkiteki/build/web/* user@000.000.000.000:/var/www/arkiteki.co/html/
```

**log.html:**
[image]

The bash script works when I run it manually, but not when a robot runs it. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you run manually? Does this script have executable permission?

Comment: Log doesnt show any errors - what actually isn't working ?

Comment: @JaPyR I enter `/Users/jcastro2/code/flutter/arkiteki/build_deploy.sh` in the terminal

Comment: @rasjani the code in the build_deploy.sh is supposed to produce output files. The first line is supposed to produce output files in my computer. It doesn't. The second line is supposed to scp them to another computer. Files are not present there either.

Comment: @JaPyR `ls -l build_deploy.sh`: `-rwxrwxrwx  1 jcastro2  staff  218 Nov 26 11:24 build_deploy.sh`

Comment: Try understand what happens with capture output of the Run Process as :
${results}=   Run Process...
Log To Console     ${results.output}

Comment: @drFunJohn no output from `Log To Console ${results.output}`

Comment: I have another crazy idea: run script as 'bash +x ...'  make prints of Bash script more verbose
. :)

Comment: sorry not `${results.output}` but `${results.stdout}` and `${result.stderr}`. So it can also let you more information.

Comment: @drFunJohn I got the error. It was because in my script I used the command 'flutter' but Robocorp did not know the path of that command, so I wrote the full path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to make a bet that the issue is with working directory.

Try changing:

```
Run Process /Users/jcastro2/code/flutter/arkiteki/build_deploy.sh   shell=yes
```

to:

```
Run Process /Users/jcastro2/code/flutter/arkiteki/build_deploy.sh   shell=yes    cwd=/Users/jcastro2/code/flutter/arkiteki/
```

or

```
Run Process /Users/jcastro2/code/flutter/arkiteki/build_deploy.sh   shell=yes    cwd=/Users/jcastro2/code/flutter/arkiteki/web
```